# Onclick not working in panel after page change

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-panel

I'm creating a small webapp using jquery mobile and php. I have an issue where I have a menu in a panel which i need to run an onclick event from. This works fine when the page has been re-loaded either using `data-ajax='false'` or running a page refresh. However when I try to use the event after a page change it just doesn't respond at all.

Here is my onclick code

```
    $('#searchOptionMap').click(function()
        {
            window.alert("map clicked ");
        });
```

and you can see the js fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/jbcvnz0p/

1. If you go to page 1 - panel click - map click the alert appears
2. If you then navigate to page 2 - panel click - map click the alert doesn't appear
3. If you stay on page 2 and click the map collapsible - alert appears

You can see that the same onclick event works for a collapsible set outside the panel, just not within it. Is there any fix for this other than using `data-ajax='false'` or running a page refresh?

Comment: it's getting alert. what you want?

Comment: no when you go to page 2 it doesnt alert, the only panel that alerts is on page 1 - ill edit my question perhaps I wasn't clear

Comment: It's alerting in second page.

Comment: which version of browser you are using?

Comment: run it in chrome, safari, ie & firefox. Are you sure your going to page 2 - panel - click map

Comment: btw, the code you posted here doesn't match the code in the fiddle

Comment: thanks, made the edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two divs with the same id, when you bind something with jQuery using an id, it only does the first one.

```
$('#searchOptionMap').click(function()
    {
        window.alert("map clicked");
    });
```

So use a class instead, or make the panel external if it's going to be the same panel for both pages.

(#searchOptionMap2 works in this case because there's only one of them)

Comment: @Janey please update your post with what you actually use. Your code above and the fiddle dont help.

Comment: this is the code that I'm using except that the panel is in an external file - I cant reproduce that in JS fiddle